# Changing a lamp switch from single to 3-way

Tags: lamp

Can I convert a single-turn switch (on/off) on a lamp to a 3-way switch?  Thank you.

Comment: Is the switch part of the socket, or part of the lamp?

Comment: you can replace the switch  easily ,,,,,, but if you want to actually have a 3-way light selection, then you will also have to replace the lamp socket and the light bulb

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside [the lamp-socket for a three-way lamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-way_lamp), you'll see *three* contacts, rather than two. Replace the existing two-contact light socket with a [three-way socket and switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002DN4LX4).

However, there are few three-way "bulbs" available, and *very* few energy-efficient [LED](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N2GLBRZ) or CFL three-way bulbs (which are a bit pricey), you'd be better off using a [small dimmer switch](https://greenled.co.nz/switches-dimmers/24-universal-led-light-dimmer.html) in the base of the lamp, or using a [remote controlled LED bulb](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N5JSF49).

All links are for reference-purposes only.

Comment: I disagree - e.g., Home Depot currently has some 3-way LED (40/60/100 W "equivalent") at ~ 2 for $8 https://www.homedepot.com/p/EcoSmart-40-60-100-Watt-Equivalent-A21-3-Way-LED-Light-Bulb-Soft-White-2-Pack-5bSA1600STQ1P01/206668081 A dimmer gives more control, but that is either a separate box or you have to figure out how to fit it into the lamp.

Comment: GE also makes a wonderful 50/150/100 bulb (you read right, the highest power is the middle position, so if you put it in a 1-way socket you get the bulb's best).  Nice and bright.    It's not cheap, but you won't replace it in a decade or more...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if the light you are placing this in has a common setup, take photos of it to your local lighting store or just take the lamp, they most likely have a 1:1 replacement. But, if the lamp is unique, you might need to do something a little more creative. (e..g, a dimmer as noted in the other answer).